# transformation does not get accumulated when using foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

## Without `foreach` (correct result)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!10] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
        [shift={(1,1)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
        [shift={(1,1)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
        [shift={(1,1)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## With `foreach` (wrong result)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!10] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
    \foreach\i in {1,2,3}{[shift={(1,1)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question

I don't understand why transformation cannot be accumulated by `\foreach`. Why?

Comment: As far as I can see, the `shift` in each cycle doesn't “carry over”, because it's evaluated in a group, so you end up drawing three times the same rectangle.

Comment: Why don't you just use `shift-{(\i,\i)}`?

Comment: Ah, well `\foreach` does that with any calculations or definitions.  You have to use `\global` to get the results out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation

> However, all transformations are local to the current TEX-group.

Your usage of `\foreach` is the same as

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!10] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
        {[shift={(1,1)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)}
        {[shift={(1,1)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)}
        {[shift={(1,1)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

You could calculate the shift from the scope index:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!10] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
       \foreach[count=\j from 1] \i in {1,2,3}
          {[shift={(\j*1,\j*1)}](0,0) rectangle(2,1)}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or you could use relative coordinates:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!10] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red](0,0)coordinate(temp) rectangle (2,1)
      foreach\i in {1,2,3}
        {([shift={(1,1)}] temp)coordinate(temp) rectangle+(2,1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both result in

[image]

Comment: Okay for `shift` transformations, and maybe for `scale`s, but what about more involved transformations, such as a transformation matrix `cm={a,b,c,d,(x0,y0)}` ?

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, each item in a foreach loop seems to be enclosed in a new tikz scope, and thus, the transformations are local and don't accumulate.

This is one way to accumulate them by hand.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\transfo{}
    \draw[red] foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}
    {
      \transfo \pgfextra{\xdef\transfo{\transfo[shift={(1,1)}]}} 
      (0,0) rectangle (2,1) 
    } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```